# Simple TCP client/server program in Java

Tags: java, tcp

Hi I'm having a small problem with my program which is a simple client/server. The client sends the contents of a textfile to the server. The text file is just ints and then the server is suppose to send back the largest prime number less than each int in the text file(if its prime it should just send back the prime number and do nothing). So for instance lets say the text file is 5 15 28. The result after running the program should be 5 13 23.

Here's my code for the Client side:

```
public class TCPClient {



        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            try{ 
                Socket mySock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12001);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(mySock.getInputStream()));
                PrintStream out = new PrintStream( mySock.getOutputStream());
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                String msg = scan.nextLine();
                out.println(msg);
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
                mySock.close();

            }catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my code for the server side:

```
public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
            ServerSocket mySock = new ServerSocket(12001);
            Socket client = mySock.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream( client.getOutputStream());

            String[] arr = in.readLine().split(" ");
            int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];

            for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
             intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
             if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
                 out.println(intarr[i]);

                }else{

                    while (!prim(--intarr[i])){

                    }

                    out.println(intarr[i]);
                }

            }           


            client.close();
            mySock.close();

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public static boolean prim(int m){
        int n=m;
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
            if(n%i == 0){
                return false;
            }

        }   
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I run this program my output is only the first number in the text file. So if my text file is 1 3 5. My output is just 1. However, my prime algorithm is at least working because if my text file is 8 for instance, my program will return 7. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `}catch (Exception e){

        }` never silently swallow excpetions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By change your server code to a simple test and printing to `System.out`

```
    String[] arr = "1 3 5 6".split(" ");
    int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
     intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
     if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
         System.out.println(intarr[i]);

        }else{
            while (!prim(--intarr[i])){
            }
            System.out.println(intarr[i]);
        }
    }
```

you can see that it works OK, but in your code, your output in writing using `println`, so your client needs to loop `System.out.println(in.readLine());` or change your server to write using one line and some delimiter

Comment: Thanks! geez that was such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In TCPServer, when printing to outputstream use print instead of println

```
  for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
         intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
         if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
             out.print(intarr[i]); // use print instead of println

            }else{

                while (!prim(--intarr[i])){

                }

                out.print(intarr[i]); // use print instead of println
            }

        }
```